# Book / Course Teaching Basic Logic Circuits Via Minecraft Redstone To A Young Target Demographic

Tags: secondary-education, primary-school

Is there a book or online course teaching basic logic and simple logic circuits via the Redstone mechanic in the game Minecraft? Similar to Nand2Tetris, but simpler and with a younger target demographic (motivated 12-14 year olds). Think starting with binary number representation, continuing with logic gates, simple circuits like ripple carry adder etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is what i will do.

I won't start with a topic like logic gates,  as i believe that there are some prerequisites you need to be familiar with to grasp it, so:

Before starting with any course, or textbook, i'd sit down and talk to him. Straight like that, i'd explain what is a system, that not everything works using the system taught, and introduce him to binary numbers.

After that, i'd teach basic electric circuits, Ohm's law, KCL and KVL.

Then, when he is ready to attack logic gates, i'd explain what a logic gate is, you can use [this](https://www.explainthatstuff.com/logicgates.html) if needed.

Now that he is ready, is there a book teaching it via minecraft? not that i know of, yet there  is the minecraft education edition, and it has some lessons regarding logic gates and applications in the game, see [this](https://education.minecraft.net/en-us/challenges/redstone-vault)

Hope i helped.

Comment: The site you pointed to teaches the concept of digital electronics just fine without any reference to electrical circuits, Ohm's law, KCL, or KLV. It's okay to choose a layer of abstraction to begin at and go from there - we do not need to understand the layer beneath that layer (or the layer beneath that, or the layer beneath that, etc) to get going. You need to start somewhere, and if the goal is to use digital electronics to gain an understanding of how it interacts with the abstract layers ABOVE it, I'd let digital electronics be the bare bottom for the moment.

Comment: Well, i respect your opinion, but i think that learning the fundamentals of every topic is necessary.

Comment: Why not learn the fundamentals behind Ohm's Law, then? Presumably we also need to understand the underlying quantum forces there before we can understand how to create an adder in digital logic? I don't mean to be overly challenging, but in truth, no matter where you enter, you will be in a layer of abstraction that is atop another layer of abstraction. Is your general rule to always enter into the abstraction that is two layers below the learning target, as you are advocating here?

Comment: If that were the rule, then I guess the natural place to begin a course on machine learning in Python would be with either assembly programming or with combinations and permutations, which are two layers removed from the target (albeit in different directions).